# Como criar gráficos no Genexus X?

Tags: genexus

Estou migrando do Gx 9 para o Gx Evolution 3 e enfrentando algumas dificuldades. Uma delas refere-se ao comando **GxMakeGraph** que não é mais suportado, porém não consigo encontrar uma explicação de como gerar gráficos nessa nova versão, tudo que encontro só serve para Web, mas estou trabalhando com gerador para windows.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Washington,

Dê uma olhada no GXChart.

Ele é um serviço que pode ser acessado via web service e te retorna a imagem de um gráfico.

Existe tbm um setup que permite instalar o GXChart no seu server, aí vc não precisa acessar o serviço online.

Veja: http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?1801,GXchart30,

Att,
Bruno

Comment: Por favor, leia [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links)

Comment: obrigado bruno, eu já conhecia o GXChart desde a versão 9, mas achei que teria algo melhor nas versões mais novas. Pesquisei bastante e não encontrei nada, como ninguém mais respondeu, vou aceitar sua resposta como correta.